# ¿Cómo imprimo este array?

Tags: angular, typescript

Tengo un observable y no se cómo pasarlo a un array de strings.

```
perfiles: string[];
    (await this.db.getProfiles()).subscribe(res => {
          console.log(res);
          this.perfiles=res
        })
```

Cuando lo imprimo me aparece esto en la consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que no se cómo iterar ese array o hacer cualquier cosa con el. Si lo meto en un forEach me dice que el array no es iterable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el array se encuentra en el atributo collections.

```
this.perfiles = res.collections;
```

ya con esto puedes iterarlo de la forma que gustes.

Comment: gracias, ya me funciona

Comment: si te funciono mi respuesta debes marcarla como correcta